# Como descompactar uma pasta em PHP?

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

Tenho um formulário onde um administrador irá preencher os dados do usuário, mas preciso que este administrador entre com uma pasta .zip onde terá fotos do usuário.

Estou usando um botão para selecionar o arquivo .zip , mas preciso descompactar este arquivo para depois utilizar o que tem dentro dele.

```
<form action='pageinicial.php' method='GET' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class='diview'>
    Certifique-se de preencher os campos login, senha, nome e email!
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th >login</th>
          <th >senha</th>
           <th >nome</th>
           <th >departamento</th>
            <th >nivel</th>      
             <th >email</th> 
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
        <tr> 
           <td id='class_td'><input type='text' name='loginusu' value=''></td>
          <td id='class_td'><input type='text' name='senhausu' value=''></td>
           <td id='class_td'><input type='text' name='nomeusu' value=''></td>
           <td id='class_td'><input type='text'  name ='departamentousu' value=''></td>
           <td id='class_td'><input type='text' name='nivelusu' value=''></td>
            <td id='class_td'><input type='email' name='emailusu' value=''></td>
        </tr>        
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' value='Adicionar'/>
<input type='file' name='foto' /><br /><br />
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

Comment: Tem algum código?

Comment: Teu formulário esta como method=GET, uploads não podem ser enviados via GET.

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento eu uso $_GET pois o administrador já está logado no sistema, pra aplicação em si não gera problemas, pois essa tela só é acessível após logar no sistema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 $arquivo = getcwd().'/arquivo-teste.zip';
 $destino = getcwd().'/';

 $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $zip->open($arquivo);
   if($zip->extractTo($destino) == TRUE)
   {
    echo 'Arquivo descompactado com sucesso.';
   }
   else
   {
    echo 'O Arquivo não pode ser descompactado.';
   }
  $zip->close();
?>
```

Ou direto:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

[Documentação Oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)

Fontes:

[Compactar](http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/compactar-pastas-e-arquivos-com-php)

[Descompactar](http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/descompactar-arquivo-com-php)